# How to copy/mirror files, but only as a placeholder with 0 file length?

Tags: windows, file, powershell, operating-system

I have multiple external hard-drives with hundreds of files.

I need to create an exact mirror of the directory/file structure of these hard-drives on my local machine, except instead of actual files, I just need a dummy placeholder file with the same name.

Eg: Ext Hard Drive contains

```
A.doc 1MB
B.doc 5MB
C\x.doc 2MB

magiccopy g: c:\test\*
```

should result int c:\test having

```
A.doc 0 bytes
B.doc 0 bytes
C\x.doc 0 bytes
```

I personally feel that this is actually a better way to search files stored across multiple hard drives without having to connect each one of them to see which one may actually contain the file.

I can write a script or a C# program(Not sure what I write can be foolproof), but would prefer a utility or built-in function to do this. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: '/' is not a valid char for windows file name or I'm missing something?

Comment: Not valid as well.... ;)

Comment: why isn't it valid? What if magiccopy took care of all my silly errors instead of being pedantic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use robocopy:

```
Robocopy.exe c:\test c:\test2 /mir /create
```

This mirrors the contents of the test folder to the test2 folder, and only creates folders and empty files.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe this question is downvoted. But hey! Strange are the ways of Internet community. They would rather be pedantic than be curious

Comment: Np ;) I think it's because you showed little effort. You didn't mention that you'd tried anything, just that you was considering. A search on google would give you the answer above (at least someone using the `/create` switch)

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback. But it is one of the harder Google searches if you already didn't know the answer. (I did plenty of searches but almost all the solutions led to mirroring and backing up data).