# How to copy a directory in a way that all files replaced by zero size files with the same filename

Tags: bash, command-line, cmd, dir

For example, I have a directory called `aaa`, and there are files named `11.txt`,`22.exe`,`33.mp3`under `aaa` directory.

Now I want to make a mirror of this directory, but I only want the structure of the directory not the contents, That is to copy `aaa` to `bbb`. Files under `bbb` should be `11.txt.zero`,`22.exe.zero`,`33.mp3.zero`. The `.zero` extension indicates that all the copied file should be of zero file size.

The directory generally contains subfolers.

How to achieve this using windows CMD and linux bash?

Comment: How many levels of dirs do you have? Just main dir and files in there or more levels? Also, what did you try so far?

Comment: @fedorqui Arbitrary level of dirs. I don't know how to do it. I only know `xcopy` can copy dir structure, but how to deal with the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "source=c:\somewhere\aaaa"
    set "target=x:\anotherplace\bbbb"

    robocopy "%source%\." "%target%\." /s /e /create
    for /r "%target%" %%a in (*) do ren "%%~fa" "%%~nxa.zero"
```

Here the `robocopy` command will handle the folder recursion and zero file generation. Once this is done, all the files in the target structure are renamed.

Comment: Awesome! Finally, the CMD batch solution!

Answer (score 2):

#### Slightly better:

Being in the directory you want to copy:

- Make the directories:

  `find -type d -exec mkdir -p ../new_dir/{} \;`
- Touch the files:

  `find -type f -exec touch ../new_dir/{}.zero \;`

#### Original approach

I would do it in two steps:

Copy all files with `rsync -r`:

```
rsync -r origin_dir/ target_dir/
```

Loop through the files in `target_dir/`, empty them and rename to `.zero`:

```
find target_dir/ -type f -exec sh -c 'f={}; > $f; mv $f $f.zero' \;
```

This of course not very optimal if the files in the original dir are quite big, because we first copy and then empty them.

#### Test

```
$ tree aa
aa
├── a
├── a1
│   └── d
├── b
├── c
└── d

1 directory, 5 files

$ ll aa/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  6 Jun 12 11:16 aa/a
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  6 Jun 12 11:16 aa/b
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  6 Jun 12 11:16 aa/c
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  6 Jun 12 11:16 aa/d

aa/a1:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  0 Jun 12 11:16 d
$ rsync -r aa/ bb/
$ tree bb
bb
├── a
├── a1
│   └── d
├── b
├── c
└── d

1 directory, 5 files
$ find bb/ -type f -exec sh -c 'f={}; > $f; mv $f $f.zero' \;
$ tree bb
bb
├── a1
│   └── d.zero
├── a.zero
├── b.zero
├── c.zero
└── d.zero

1 directory, 5 files
$ ll bb/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  0 Jun 12 11:23 bb/a.zero
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  0 Jun 12 11:23 bb/b.zero
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  0 Jun 12 11:23 bb/c.zero
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  0 Jun 12 11:23 bb/d.zero

bb/a1:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 0 Jun 12 11:23 d.zero
```

Comment: All linux solution? I want one using windowns CMD

Comment: And I want a unicorn. Do you think this is a coding service? Post your attempts, give feedback on the answers and learn how to ask by reading [ask]. Also, if you have cygwin this solution is perfectly suitable for Windows.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just want to know a way to realize this in windows CMD batch, because I seldom use linux. And I viewed stack overflow as a treasure house for coding, since I learned a lot from other people's questions and answers, and they solve most of my problem. I asked for linux solutions, because I thought maybe someone else want to realize the same thing in linux, then he won't have to open another question, just learn it here. I am so sorry if I make you unhappy for asking too much.

Answer (score 1):

at first copy directory structure:

```
find aaa -type d -print  | sed 's/^aaa/bbb/' | xargs mkdir -p
```

at second, touch the files:

```
find aaa -type f -print | sed 's/^aaa/bbb/' | sed 's/$/\.zero/' | xargs touch
```

and result:

```
[trak_000.COGITATOR] ➤ ls -lR aaa bbb
aaa:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x    1 trak_000 UsersGrp         0 Jun 12 12:20 q1

aaa/q1:
total 1
-rw-rw-r--    1 trak_000 UsersGrp       194 Jun 12 12:20 test1.txt

bbb:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x    1 trak_000 UsersGrp         0 Jun 12 12:24 q1

bbb/q1:
total 0
-rw-rw-r--    1 trak_000 UsersGrp         0 Jun 12 12:24 test1.txt.zero
```

Comment: And for Windows, use [Gnu on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki). Don't forget to replace the apostrophes (`'`) with quotes (`"`) in the `cmd.exe` command prompt.

Comment: Using `find`, then `sed` and then `xargs` looks a bit overkilling. May be best to rely on `find` together with `-exec` for the same.

Comment: @fedorqui there are few methods to vivisect a banny :)

Answer (score 0):

Use tree command to get recursive list of source folder and then to create zero size structure use mkdir for subdirs and touch for files.

Answer (score 0):

For a Windows command line option, one can create a zero-length mirror copy of a directory structure (and contents) with Robocopy:

```
robocopy <source> <destination> /e /create
```

/e - Copy Subfolders, including Empty Subfolders.

/create - CREATE directory tree structure + zero-length files only.

One can also substitute `/mir` for `/e`

/mir - MIRror a directory tree - equivalent to /PURGE plus all subfolders (/E)

The above command would need modified to append '.zero' to each file, but it would appear this zero-length folder structure mirror might have been what was desired in the first place.

This has been quite helpful when testing some dangerous commands on a wide variety of data.

References:

[How to copy/mirror files, but only as a placeholder with 0 file length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828536/how-to-copy-mirror-files-but-only-as-a-placeholder-with-0-file-length)

https://superuser.com/questions/332845/easiest-way-to-copy-a-directory-recursively-creating-0-length-files

https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy